# Different webpages depending on the PC

Tags: html, joomla, dns, ip

two day ago I migrated a server.

The problem is, nowadays when I access from one computer I can see the new webpage but when I access from other one I still see the old one.

How is this possible? what is wrong?

Comment: This needs a *lot* more information to become answerable. Where are the servers located, what addresses are they using, what kind of machine are you trying to access the site from, etc. etc.

Comment: DNS cache? Hardcoded IP in hosts file? Caching proxies? There are a ton of variables...

Comment: the server is my VPS, and I when I access from any part I see the new webpage but there is a office where they just can see the old web and the email is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because they use different DNS information.

Different DNS servers get the updated information at different times. It may be as long as 48 hours until all DNS servers are updated.

The DNS information may also be cached in the computer, so it may be another hour or so after the information in the DNS server is updated until the computers using it has updated their information.